# Almost identical general statement with different citations – is this a problem?

Tags: citations, plagiarism

Paper X states that

> A is bla bla, but also referred to as B [1] and C [2].

I recently wrote:

> A is referred to as B [3] and C [4].

where Paper [3] and [4] are about the same topic as papers [1] and [2], respectively.

Would this almost identical sentence be an issue (in the sense of plagiarism), in particular since I cite Paper X for another reason elsewhere in my paper?

Comment: Then I don't see why you need to cite their sentence about [0] being referred to as [2] and [1]. Many similar papers have been written and will continue to be written ...

Answer (score 1):

This form of basic sentence is common and hence would not be regarded as plagiarism. You are not taking any distinct sentence and hopefully you are not providing the same references as specified in the first sentence.

Plagiarism occurs when you use the work of another without proper attribution. I would not consider your query to fit in this description.

Comment: thanks. no i use two different papers identifying the same thing.

Comment: Then by all means, this isn't plagiarism, @vasper.